# Proof of Compactness Theorem’s failure in finite models

Tags: model-theory

I have a question on Jouko Väänänen’s proof on Compactness Theorem’s failure in finite model theory (FMT) in his “A Short Course on Finite Model Theory” in section 1.1 in page 5 at [https://www.lacl.fr/~pvanier/cours/2015-2016/lm/articles/shortcoursefmt.pdf](https://www.lacl.fr/%7Epvanier/cours/2015-2016/lm/articles/shortcoursefmt.pdf)

In this proof, it says $T=\left\{\neg \phi_1, \neg \phi_2,\ldots, \neg\phi_n,\ldots\right\}$, which is infinite.  But in the remark, it says $T=\left\{\neg c_n=c_m: n\neq m\right\}$ where $c_n$, $c_m$ are constants.  Because it talks about Finite Models that has a finite domain/universe, therefore the number of constants have to be finite.  Thus, $T$ is finite.   It seems there are two definitions for theory $T$, and they are contradicting.  Did I miss anything?

Comment: I'm not sure why this got a downvote, or what additional context is being looked for. (That said, in the future you should use tex more consistently.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write

> "Because it talks about Finite Models that has a finite domain/universe, therefore the number of constants have to be finite"

This isn't true: there's no rule that says that you can't have a language larger than the universe being looked at. Indeed, even in classical model theory there are [interesting questions about uncountable languages and countable structures](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453900/is-there-a-complete-uncountable-theory-with-two-countable-models).

But if you want, you can whip up a finite-language counterexample: instead of infinitely many constants, use a single constant symbol $c$ and a unary function symbol $f$. We wind up looking at the theory $$\{\forall x,y(f(x)=f(y)\leftrightarrow x=y)\}\cup\{f(c)\not=c, f(f(c))\not=c, f(f(f(c)))\not=c,...\}.$$ Every finite subtheory of this theory has a finite model, but the whole theory does not have a finite model.

Comment: Thanks. I didn’t say the language has to be finite, just the number of sentences in T is finite per the 2nd definition of T which seems different from the 1st definition of T, both of which are in the same paragraph in section 1.1 in page 5 at https://www.lacl.fr/~pvanier/cours/2015-2016/lm/articles/shortcoursefmt.pdf

That confuses me.  Any thought?

Comment: @Mike $T$ is a purely syntactic object; its definition has nothing to do with the size of any particular structure being considered. Since the **language** $\{c_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is infinite, $T$ itself is infinite.

Comment: In particular, in the second definition in your text the indices $m,n$ range over **natural numbers** as opposed to elements of any particular finite structure.

Comment: Thanks. Understood now.